Automatic token refresh using Admin SDK Python
I've made a simple REST service using FastAPI + Admin SDK (firebase_admin).
import os
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, messaging
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
from pydantic import BaseModel
from dotenv import load_dotenv


load_dotenv()
cred = credentials.Certificate(os.getenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"))
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)


app = FastAPI()


class PushNotificationModel(BaseModel):
    title: str
    body: str
    token: str


def send_push_notification(title: str, body: str, token: str) -> str:
    try:
        message = messaging.Message(
            notification=messaging.Notification(title=title, body=body), token=token
        )
        response = messaging.send(message)
        return response
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=500, detail=f"Error sending push notification: {str(e)}"
        )


@app.post("/send-push/")
async def send_push(notification: PushNotificationModel):
    response = send_push_notification(
        title=notification.title, body=notification.body, token=notification.token
    )
    return {"message": "Push notification sent", "response": response}


And also created script that sends POST-request to my REST to send push to device using its token.
import requests


def send_test_push():
    url = "http://localhost:8000/send-push/"
    data = {
        "title": "Test title",
        "body": "Test body",
        "token": "bla-bla-bla",
    }
    response = requests.post(url, json=data)
    print(response.json())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    send_test_push()


I use the newest version of Google Firebase Messaging and also I read this. Should I try to update access token when it exprires using refresh token? As I read Admin SDK can do this for me automatically.
